# kmeans clustering transform method specifying centroids

Tags: scikit-learn

In the scikit-learn kmeans source code, there is an optional argument `y` that can be specified (`transform(X[, y])`); however when I examined the source code for `transform`, it seems that nowhere does it deal with `y` in the case that it is specified. What is the purpose of this optional argument (it is not clear in the documentation either)?

As an addendum; I was wondering if there was any way to specify the centroids in the transform function if they're already computed previously. (Or if there was any other function to do this in scikit-learn).

Answer (score 2):

#### Centroid specification

You could just overwrite `kmeans_object.cluster_centers_` with your own centroids. But it might be better just using `init` with these centers and do some iterations.

See the available attributes in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn-cluster-kmeans).

Comment: The problem is that I have some data and I want to transform it to cluster distance space (as the function transform does) with respect to previous calculated centroids. I don't want to recluster or recompute centroids. Of course I could write a function to do this myself, but I figured if there was any easy way with sklearn, it would be faster than my own implementation and easier for me.

Comment: Interesting. In general i would not mix libraries like that. So what are the constraints? You don't want to recluster because of time needed or something else? I would expect, that, given the centroids, only a minimal number of reiterations is performed (actually something like 1, as your init would be a locally optimal solution; when using the same metrics, there is nothing to improve).

Comment: I generate centroids based on some training data and then I want to transform the testing data also into the same cluster space as the training data. The constraint isn't computation time or anything. I just want to transform to the old clustering space with the old centroids. I guess I could take the kmeans object and just keep it permanently and transform with that in that case.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question about the seemingly pointless argument `y`. You are correct, in many cases, Scikit-Learn allows users to pass a `y` argument that actually doesn't affect the outcome of the method.

As explained in their [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#apis-of-scikit-learn-objects):

> y might be ignored in the case of unsupervised learning. However, to
>   make it possible to use the estimator as part of a pipeline that can
>   mix both supervised and unsupervised transformers, even unsupervised
>   estimators need to accept a y=None keyword argument in the second
>   position that is just ignored by the estimator. For the same reason,
>   fit_predict, fit_transform, score and partial_fit methods need to
>   accept a y argument in the second place if they are implemented.

So it's all to make the code easier to write. Imagine that you have a pipeline that looks like this:

step 0: some normalization
step 1: K-means to transform the data in another space
step 2: classification step

Step 1 obviously doesn't need `y` to work, but if you have to write the code to make the pipeline apply all of these steps, it'll be easier to simply pass X, y into all transformers, rather than having to worry about whether each individual transformer takes a `y` or not